# Pull to refresh data duplication

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, joomla, ionic-framework

I am creating an Ionic application that is pulling articles from a joomla K2 website. I am using $http and just ending my url off with '?format=json' and that is working perfectly. However the website I am pulling data from updates its articles every few minutes so I need a way for the user to be able to refresh the page. I have implemented Ionics pull to refresh and it is working swell except for the fact that instead of just pulling in new articles it just appends all the articles to my array. Is there anyway to just maybe iterate over current articles timestamps or IDs (I am caching articles in localStorage) to just bring in new articles? My factory looks like this:

```
.factory('Articles', function ($http) {
    var articles = [];
       storageKey = "articles";

    function _getCache() {
        var cache = localStorage.getItem(storageKey );
        if (cache)
            articles = angular.fromJson(cache);
    }


    return {
        all: function () {
            return $http.get("http://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=http://mexamplesite.com/index.php?format=json").then(function (response) {
                articles = response.data.items;
                console.log(response.data.items);
                return articles;
            });
        },

        getNew: function () {
            return $http.get("http://jsonp.afeld.me/?url=http://mexamplesite.com/index.php?format=json").then(function (response) {
                articles = response.data.items;
                return articles;
            });
        },

        get: function (articleId) {
            if (!articles.length) 
                _getCache();
            for (var i = 0; i < articles.length; i++) {
                if (parseInt(articles[i].id) === parseInt(articleId)) {
                    return articles[i];
                }
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
});
```

and my controller:

```
.controller('GautengCtrl', function ($scope, $stateParams, $timeout, Articles) {
    $scope.articles = [];
    Articles.all().then(function(data){
        $scope.articles = data;
        window.localStorage.setItem("articles", JSON.stringify(data));
    }, 

    function(err) {
       if(window.localStorage.getItem("articles") !== undefined) {
          $scope.articles = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("articles"));
        }
    }

    );

    $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    Articles.getNew().then(function(articles){
      $scope.articles = articles.concat($scope.articles);
      $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
    });
  };
})
```

Comment: The best would be to use query parameters to only fetch the articles that you don't already have from the server

Comment: The problem is that I cannot find any documentation on joomla's K2 JSON functionality. It does provide a limit option however it does not seem to work with this kind of functionality in mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use underscore.js to simple filtering functionality.

For example:

get all id's of already loaded items (I believe there is some unique fields like id)

http://underscorejs.org/#pluck

```
var loadedIds = _.pluck($scope.articles, 'id');
```

Reject all items, if item.id is already in loadedIds list.

http://underscorejs.org/#reject

http://underscorejs.org/#contains

```
var newItems = _.reject(articles, function(item){ 
   return _.contains(loadedIds, item.id); 
});
```

Join new items and existings:

```
$scope.articles = newItems.concat($scope.articles);
```

or

http://underscorejs.org/#union

```
$scope.articles = _.union(newItems, $scope.articles);
```

Actually _.union() can manage and remove duplicates, but I would go for manual filtering using item.id.

Comment: Thanx a lot! worked perfectly. Surprised this sort of functionality isn't built into angular